# How to show that the charge conjugation reverses the charge of a state?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, symmetry, charge-conjugation

*How to show that the charge conjugation operator reverses the charge(s) of a (fermionic or bosonic) state?*

Let us consider a spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ fermionic state of momentum $\textbf{k}$ and spin projection $s$ given by $a_s^\dagger(\textbf{k})|0\rangle$. The normal ordered charge operator associated with the symmetry $\psi\to e^{iq}\psi$ is given by $$Q=q\int d^3\textbf{p}\sum\limits_{s=1,2}\Big[a_s^\dagger(\textbf{p})a_s(\textbf{p})-b_s^\dagger(\textbf{p})b_s(\textbf{p})\Big]$$ where $a^\dagger, b^\dagger$ are respectively the particle and antiparticle creation operators.  It is a trivial matter to show that $$Qa_s^\dagger(\textbf{k})|0\rangle=qa_s^\dagger(\textbf{k})|0\rangle~~ \text{and}~~ Qb_s^\dagger(\textbf{k})|0\rangle=-qb_s^\dagger(\textbf{k})|0\rangle.$$

Now, the charge conjugation operator is given by $$C=i\gamma^2\gamma^0.$$ I want to show that $$Q(Ca_s^\dagger(\textbf{k})|0\rangle)=-q(Ca_s^\dagger(\textbf{k})|0\rangle)$$ or something like $$Q(Ca_s^\dagger(\textbf{k})|0\rangle)=b_s^\dagger(\textbf{k})|0\rangle.$$

*Am I on the right track? If yes, any hint how to act C on the state $a_s^\dagger(\textbf{k})|0\rangle$?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track.

The rest of this answer is about the distinction between the charge conjugation *operator* $C_{op}$ and the charge conjugation *matrix* $C_{mat}$. If this misses the point of the question, let me know and I'll revise (or delete) the answer.

The field operator $\psi$ is an array of operators — a Dirac spinor whose four components *each* act as an individual operator on the Hilbert space. A Dirac matrix $\gamma^\mu$ does not act on the Hilbert space; it only mixes the components of the field operator $\psi$. When we write an expression like $\gamma^0\psi|0\rangle$, we are mixing *matrix* notation (it is a column matrix in which each component is a whole state-vector) and *operator* notation (because each component of $\gamma^0\psi$ is a different operator acting on $|0\rangle$).

The charge conjugation *operator* $C_{op}$ exchanges states of the form 
$$
\int d^3x\ \sum_n f_n(x)\psi_n(x)|0\rangle
\tag{1a}
$$
with states of the form
$$
\int d^3x\ \sum_n g_n(x)\psi^*_n(x)|0\rangle,
\tag{1a}
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are ordinary functions with the same number of components as $\psi$, and
where $\psi^*_n$ denotes the operator adjoint of $\psi_n$. (If the components of $\psi$ are $\psi_n$, then the components of $\psi^\dagger$ are $\psi^*_n$.) We want $C_{op}$ to exchange these because $\psi$ has components that create antiparticles (and components that annihilate particles), and $\psi^\dagger$ has components that create particles (and components that annihilate antiparticles).

The key point is that the charge conjugation *matrix* $C_{mat}$ is used to define the charge conjugation *operator* like this:
$$
  C_{op}\psi C_{op}^{-1} \sim C_{mat}\psi^*
\tag{2}
$$
where $\psi^*$ denotes the component-wise operator adjoint of $\psi$, without any matrix transpose. Again, this equation mixes matrix notation and operator notation. On the left-hand side, $\psi$ is a column-matrix, and the operator transformation $C_{op}\cdots C_{op}^{-1}$ acts on each individual element of this matrix. On the right-hand side, $\psi^*$ is again a column matrix, the transpose of the row matrix $\psi^\dagger$, and $C_{mat}$ is a square matrix of ordinary numbers; this matrix product mixes the components of $\psi^*$ with each other.

The matrix $C_{mat}$ can be expressed as some combination of Dirac matrices (as shown in the question), but an explicit expression for the operator $C_{op}$ requires more. We could presumably express it as some combination of field operators (or creation and annihilation operators), but usually we just define it through its *effect* on the field operators, as in equation (2).  After writing $\psi$ in terms of creation/annihilation operators, equation (2) tells us how $C_{op}$ affects them, too.

The matrix $C_{mat}$ should be chosen so that the effect of $C_{op}$ on the current $q\overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi$ is equivalent to reversing the sign of the charge $q$, because this is the current that couples to $A_\mu$ in the Lagrangian. According to this requirement, different representations for the $\gamma$-matrices lead to different representations for the matrix $C_{mat}$. One common representation leads to $C_{mat}\propto\gamma^0\gamma^2$, as stated in the question.

When the matrix $C_{mat}$ is chosen to satisfy that requirement, the operator $C_{op}$ will do something like
$$
  C_{op}a^\dagger C_{op}^{-1} \sim b^\dagger
\hskip2cm
  C_{op}a C_{op}^{-1} \sim b
$$
as anticipated by the question. Then, since the vacuum is invariant under $C_{op}$, we have
$$
  C_{op}a^\dagger C_{op}^{-1}|0\rangle
 =  C_{op}a^\dagger |0\rangle
 \sim  b^\dagger |0\rangle.
$$
The fact that $C_{op}$ reverses the *charge* of the state is guaranteed by the fact that it reverses the sign of the charge density operator:
$$
C_{op}QC_{op}^{-1}=-Q
\hskip1cm
\text{with }
Q\sim q\overline{\psi}\gamma^0\psi = q\psi^\dagger\psi\sim q(a^\dagger a - b^\dagger b).
$$
I glossed over a lot of details in this answer. The main point is that $C_{op}$ and $C_{mat}$ are two different things — related, but different.